# check if user input contains set element in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, user-input

```py
spam = {"make a lot of money","buy now","subscribe this","click this"}
text = input("Enter your text: ")
if (text in spam):
    print("It is spam")
else:
    print("it is not spam")
```

this code snippet is not working for the entered input
ex  - text = "make a lot of money" , Output - "It is spam"
but if text = "click this to make a lot of money", Output - "it is not spam"

What is the possible explanation and the solution using the `set` method?

Comment: There is no element in `spam` that is identical to the string `"click this to make a lot of money"`. The `in` operator of a `set` doesn't do partial matches.

Comment: What expects to get if user's input just *money* or *buy*?

Comment: @DanielHao, Thank you for asking, It will show the output - "It is not spam" as money or buy is not a element of the set spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, I think your main problem is that you're not checking each item in the set, so unless the text is an exact match, you will not get the correct answer

```
spam = {"make a lot of money","buy now","subscribe this","click this"}
text = input("Enter your text: ")

if any([x in text for x in spam]):
    print("It is spam")
else:
    print("it is not spam")
```

Using `any` allows you to compare each item in the set to the input to judge if at least one of them matches.

Comment: I believe it can go without the ```[``` and ```]``` square bracket, to make it ```generator expression```